# Possible to run flask web app on linux server without web access and access through tunnel?

Tags: python, linux, flask, ssh-tunnel

I work on a linux cluster that is behind a firewall. It does not have web access.

I had this idea I could try to run flask and direct it to a port I know is open (5901 for vnc), and then tunnel that port and view it in my browser.

It's not working so far. Is this possible at all?

Here is what I'm doing:

**helloflask.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5901)
        #app.run()
```

I run `python helloflask.py` then

```
ssh -L 5901:<inner server>:5901 <outer server>
```

Then I navigate to `localhost:5901`. Nothing. I also tried `links localhost:5901` and `links <server>:5901`, but again nothing.

Is it possible there is some way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to access the flask app running on a remote server via ssh tunneling from your local machine?

Comment: Yes. Sorry if that wasn't clear. My ultimate goal is really to run a jupyter notebook. But I'm just doing proof of principle with a tiny flask app because it is simple and I have more control.

Comment: I think if there a bind ip related to flask configuration. you have to comment that

Comment: @abalter see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this :
Run your flask app or notebook on the remote server on any port. Say for example port 5000.

On your local machine run below command to establish the ssh tunnelling :

```
ssh -D 8123 -f -C -q -N username@remotesrrver
```

The port 8123 is arbitrary here it can be any allowed port on your local machine. Then setup one of your browser (Fire fox may be) to use socks proxy on port 8123
Make sure that the traffic is proxied for localhost also. By default Firefox disable proxying for localhost. Once these are established you should be able to go to http://localhost:5000 on your browser to hit the app /notebook running on the remote machine

And your hellowflask.py should be like something below for it to work

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5901)
  #app.run()
```

Comment: Just need one adjustment: I can't directly access `remoteserver`. I have to tunnel through `anotherserver`. I'll try tunneling `remoteserver:5000` through `anotherserver` in another terminal and see if that works. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Hmmm. Didn't get that to work. I went on the the VPN so it looked like I was on campus and I don't need to hop to the server. Question: When I run `python helloflask.py`, I get the prompt back. And `ps -ef | grep python` doesn't show anything for me. Would this be the expected behavior if the flask server is running? I'm afraid it's dying. Why would that be?

Comment: I got jupyter to work on the VPN. Started `jupyter notebook`, did `ssh -L 8888:localhost:8888 remoteserver` and found the notebook at `localhost:8888`. So it can at least work on campus. But flask is still quitting.

Comment: @abalter Looks like your flask is failing to start , are you seeing anything in the logs when starting flask ? How are you running flask? with gunicorn?

Comment: I installed flask with conda. I'm starting the file in the original question with `python helloflask.py`. What logs could I look at?

Comment: So, I did this: `python -i helloflask.py`. Flask quite and I couldn't connect. So then at the python prompt, I did `app.run(port=5001)`, tunneled port 5001, and then I was able to connect. So I need to figure out why flask is quitting.

Comment: Oh boy!  Your hellow.py is the culprit!. your if block should be outside the hello method. i.e the 'if __name__ == "__main__":' should be same level as the method hellow.  I have updated my answer to show you how to do it.

Comment: Oh, that's so obvious! I copy/pasted the code from the web into vim and the indentation got messed up. I screwed up fixing it. Yup, that was it.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest trying something like `pyngrok` to programmatically manage an `ngrok` tunnel for you? Full disclosure, I am the developer of it. Flask example [here](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrations.html#flask), but it's as easy as installing `pyngrok`:

```
pip install pyngrok
```

and using it:

```py
from pyngrok import ngrok

# <NgrokTunnel: "http://<public_sub>.ngrok.io" -> "http://localhost:5000">
http_url = ngrok.connect(5000)
```